# Select with list among the variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to query my DB to find a specific Group and all comments regarding that Group. I can do this easily with direct SQL (SqlCommand) but with linq to sql I run into problems regarding the select clause of the query.

These are my DTO that are created by my query:

```
public class GroupDTO
{
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public String Groupname { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public List<GroupCommentDTO> GroupComments { get; set; }

        public class GroupCommentDTO
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public String Username { get; set; }
            public String Comment { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Could anyone please show me the linq to sql way of the above using my classes? It's the GroupComments list i'm having problems with populating correctly in the same query. I want to select all groups with all comments, for every comment i want a username and the comment. A group might have no comments so a left join is probably needed.

[image]

I've tried something like this.

```
 var query = (from groups in db.Groups
                 from gc in db.GroupComments
                    .Where( comment => groups.GroupId == comment.GroupId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from users in db.Users
                 where users.UserId == gc.UserId
                 select new GroupDTO
                 {
                    GroupId = groups.GroupId,
                    Groupname = groups.Groupname,
                    GroupComments = // How can i fill this arraylist of comments?
                 }).ToList<GroupDTO>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be really easy:

```
List<GroupCommentDTO> comments = context.Users
                                        .First(x => x.GroupId == groupId)
                                        .GroupComments
```

unless your navigation properties are not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something along:

```
var your_comments = 
       from group in your_collection_of_groupDTOs.GroupComments
       join user in Users on user.ID equals group.UserId
       select new { user.UserName, user.UserId, group.Comment };
```

---

As per comments:
Seems that your issue is type converting. I would suggest having a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), or googling yields results like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c6be5f36-c314-4f2e-ae38-4b3ad4f1e028/how-to-convert-listof-class-to-another-listof-classc-l?forum=csharpgeneral), and so on.

Also, you could update the question with this information, if reading the first link doesn't solve the problem

Comment: did you try `GroupComments = groups.GroupComment` ?

Comment: Yes but they are different types. GroupComments is my own class type GroupComment<GroupCommentsDTO> while the groups.GroupComment is the type from database, GroupComment<GroupComments>.

Comment: do you have a simple way of casting them?

Comment: That is pretty much my question :) I havent figured out how to do that list casting of every element to a GroupComment<GroupCommentsDTO>